# SEO problems with Ember Application after switching to HTTPS

Tags: ember.js, seo

We've been working on an Ember Application recently and we have switched the site over to HTTPS from HTTP.

The result of this was that both http and https results were in google search results even though the correct re-directs were put in place.

We were thinking about maybe using URL Removal Request in Google Webmaster Tools to solve this.

We currently have both http and https sites listed on google webmaster as well, and we can see http site is still getting impressions.

Any advice on this at all?

Answer (score 0):

Patience. The http pages will be replaced by https pages. Google need to recrawl your pages one by one.

One way to accelerate this is to submit a sitemap in Google Webmaster Tool with the http links to your pages and a dummy recent `lastmod` date. Assuming redirects have been implemented properly, this should accelerate the process.

Do not use the URL Remove Request. That would hurt your traffic.